# How to get hash key for Facebook Login on Android

Tags: android, facebook, hash, xamarin

Creating an app with Xamarin that has Facebook Login. On Android I create a hash key, add it to the developers console on Facebook, but I get an error when I login with my app that the hashkey does not match the one at facebook. Do anyone know how to either get the hash key from my app trough code with C# or why the hashkeys does not match?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you upload the debug version of the application or an signed version? When debugging the applications are usually signed with a standard certificate, but when you export and sign an application you use your own created certificate. Different certificate, different key-hash.

This snippet will write your keyhash in the console, so run the application after signing and check the console. Notice! Replace `<your package name>` with your package-name

```
PackageInfo info = this.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo ("<your package name>", PackageInfoFlags.Signatures);

            foreach (Android.Content.PM.Signature signature in info.Signatures)
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.GetInstance("SHA");
                md.Update(signature.ToByteArray());

                string keyhash = Convert.ToBase64String(md.Digest());
                Console.WriteLine("KeyHash:",  keyhash);
            }
```

Snippet found on [Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11957/facebook-login)

Comment: We are a little noob on the Android side of Xamarin, but where do I put this codesnippet? I tried to use it in MainActivity but the hashkey results in a blank string.

Comment: @user3690826 Add the snippet to a place of your choice, I would recommend in the method that runs on application start. If the keyhash resulted in a empty string you might have written the wrong package-name. It should be like e.g `com.me.myapp`